# Avoiding loss of significance without series expansion

Tags: numerical-analysis

I have a problem on an assignment where I have to reduce the loss of significance due to subtraction for a function

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

without using a series expansion. I can get part way through the problem but get stuck where I can't remove the subtraction in the square root:

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x-\sqrt{x^2-1}}\cdot\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$

$$x\sin(x)+\sin(x)\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

I still have the $x^2-1$ term in the square root which would cause loss of significance, I'm not sure how to get rid of this term or change it to a positive.

Comment: Hint: $x$ and $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ are never close enough in magnitude for that subtraction to lose significance. To see why, suppose that $x + \epsilon = \sqrt{x^2-1}$ (where $\epsilon$ is so small that $\epsilon^2 \approx 0$) and see what that implies. By the way, even if that weren't true, you'd still have a similar problem: what does $\sin x \left( x + \sqrt{x^2-1} \right)$ give you when $-x \approx \sqrt{x^2-1}$? But that can't happen for a similar reason, so that's not an issue. So actually, $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ is the only problem you have to solve here.